# looping with range in Go

Tags: loops, go

Correct me if I'm wrong, there are only 3 types of loops in Go.

Type1 (The most basic type, with a single condition):

`for i <= 3 {...}`

Type2 (Classical for-loop)

`for j := 7; j <= 9; j++ {...}`

Type3 (infinite loop rely on break)

`for {...break}`

Then I come across this for loop that sums the value from array

```
nums := []int{2, 3, 4}
sum := 0
for _, num := range nums {
    sum += num
}
fmt.Println("sum:", sum)//"sum: 9"
```

Is the above `for-loop` to be considered **Type1** where it automatically applies `<=` and range of nums as max value? Can I in any way change the value? maybe I need two extra loops? Can we apply something like `range + 2`?

Comment: The language is "Go", not "GO", not "`GO`". There's no reason to YELL or to `quote` the name of the language in all of your questions.

Comment: This is clearly answered (including a "there are three forms" statement) in [the language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for):

> The Go for loop is similar to—but not the same as—C's. It unifies for and while and there is no do-while. There are three forms, only one of which has semicolons.
>
> ```
> // Like a C for
> for init; condition; post { }
>
> // Like a C while
> for condition { }
>
> // Like a C for(;;)
> for { }
> ```

It continues:

> If you're looping over an array, slice, string, or map, or reading from a channel, a range clause can manage the loop.
>
> ```
> for key, value := range oldMap {
>         newMap[key] = value
> }
> ```

---

From this I think of `range` loops as a `for condition { }` loop, where the *condition* (such as it is) is that the variables being designated as the values of the array/slice/string/map/chan are not nil, though in practice even explicitly `nil` values work

```
for _, v := range []interface{}{nil, nil, nil, nil} {
    // will still iterate four times
}
```

---

In reality it might be more useful to think of Go's `for` loop as a contextual combination of a C-style `for init; condition; post` loop, a classical `while` loop, and a more modern [`foreach`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) loop.

Comment: ahh..I see..much better example for using `range` than the one I had

Answer (score 0):

**Type1** will work almost like `while` in other languages. Since there is no `while` in go language it uses for in that case.

**Type2** is the classic `for` loop like in other languages as you have also stated.

**Type3** is used to range over various data structures like arrays, slice, maps

> range on arrays and slices provides both the index and value for each
>   entry like the example you have given

```
nums := []int{2, 3, 4}
sum := 0
for _, num := range nums {
    sum += num
}
fmt.Println("sum:", sum)//"sum: 9"
```

> range on map iterates over key/value pairs.

```
kvs := map[string]string{"a": "apple", "b": "banana"}
for k, v := range kvs {
    fmt.Printf("%s -> %s\n", k, v)
}
```

> range on strings iterates over Unicode code points. The first value is
>   the starting byte index of the rune and the second the rune itself.

```
for i, c := range "go" {
    fmt.Println(i, c)
}
```

For more information, Check [Go by example](https://gobyexample.com/range) website for usage of range

Comment: Probably worth putting an explicit code block for range-ing over a `chan` too, since you listed the others.

Comment: @AdamSmith yeah thanks for advice but I just given the example of looping over data structures using range for OP's question and mentioned that there is no while in Golang instead we use `for` in place of that.